# Google API - forces to Grant Permission Every time

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-client

I am using Google API PHP Client. And every time i try to login I am forced to grant permissions to the apps.

Below is my code. I am basically accessing Google API for Analytics

```
require_once 'lib/apiClient.php';
require_once 'lib/contrib/apiAnalyticsService.php';
session_start();

$client = new apiClient();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Analytics");

$client->setClientId('7xxxx');
$client->setClientSecret('xxxx');
$client->setRedirectUri('xxxx');
$client->setDeveloperKey('xxxx');

$analytics = new apiAnalyticsService($client);

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate();
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    $profileId = getProfileIds($analytics);

    echo "<select>";
    foreach ($profileId as $profiles) {
        echo "<option value=\"" . $profiles['profileId'] . "\">" . $profiles['name'] .
            "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";

} else {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
}
```

What option can we pass to **createAuthUrl()** ??

Comment: Shouldn't you just use the token you store in `$_SESSION['token']` if it's available?

Comment: @EduardoCereto can you please elaborate. I was thinking why do i need to call for the new object. Could u share the best practices

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By Setting

```
$client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');
```

It will automatically redirect if the account has access to the apis. By Default its **'force'**