# google login oauth2 re-ask access every time

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I'm trying to use google oauth2 api for my login system. It's almost working, users give access to my web application, I read infos and connect users. Issue is, once they leave or change browser, get back on my website they're asked again to give access.

I don't need offline access as I'm not using any API calls other than checking in the user. Anyway I'm stuck and need some help there !

I'm using google php library (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2) and I even set ApprovalPrompt to auto. Still no luck.

my code:

```
public function googleLogin()
{
    $this->set('connect', "Google login");
    $client = new apiClient();
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');
    $client->setApplicationName("Authentication");
    $client->setClientId(G_OAUTH2_APP_ID);
    $client->setClientSecret(G_OAUTH2_SECRET);
    $client->setRedirectUri(G_REDIRECT_URI);
    $client->setDeveloperKey(G_DEV_KEY);
    $oauth2 = new apiOauth2Service($client);

    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $client->authenticate();
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    }

    if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['token']);
        $client->revokeToken();
    }
    //print_r($client->getAccessToken()); exit;

    if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
        $user = $oauth2->Guserinfo->get();


        // These fields are currently filtered through the PHP sanitize filters.
        // See http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php
        //$email = filter_var($user['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        //$img = filter_var($user['picture'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);

        // The access token may have been updated lazily.
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

        //do stuff with user data
        $data = $this->linkUser($user, "google");
        if ($data['state']=="createUser") {
            $this->set("data",$data);
        }

    } else {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        header("Location: " . $authUrl);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I added the line `$client->setAccessType("online");`
I don't know yet if this is the only thing I had to do to make it work or if I have a bug between browsers/OS:
Last time I tried on lion/chrome it didn't work but it's okay on w7/firefox. Well this or I'm simply loosing my mind :p

Comment: i have the same problem and i am not able to find a proper solution for this , if i turn that to offline it gives an error when my token expires and if i do this method this only works till he doesnt close his browser

Answer (score 11):

On another question here: [Google API - forces to Grant Permission Every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851358/google-api-forces-to-grant-permission-every-time)

Someone pointed out you can do this:

`$client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem that seems to be solved eliminating $client->revokeToken(), moving the logout stuff before the login.

I don't know if avoiding to invalidate the token is a valid idea or not, but it seems to work.

Try with this one:

```
public function googleLogin()
{
    $this->set('connect', "Google login");
    $client = new apiClient();
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');
    $client->setApplicationName("Authentication");
    $client->setClientId(G_OAUTH2_APP_ID);
    $client->setClientSecret(G_OAUTH2_SECRET);
    $client->setRedirectUri(G_REDIRECT_URI);
    $client->setDeveloperKey(G_DEV_KEY);
    $oauth2 = new apiOauth2Service($client);

    // I moved the logout stuff here, without invalidating the token
    if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['token']);            
    }

    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $client->authenticate();
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    }

    /* // I solved getting this stuf commented
    if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['token']);
        $client->revokeToken();
    }*/
    //print_r($client->getAccessToken()); exit;

    if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
        $user = $oauth2->Guserinfo->get();


        // These fields are currently filtered through the PHP sanitize filters.
        // See http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php
        //$email = filter_var($user['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        //$img = filter_var($user['picture'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);

        // The access token may have been updated lazily.
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

        //do stuff with user data
        $data = $this->linkUser($user, "google");
        if ($data['state']=="createUser") {
            $this->set("data",$data);
        }

    } else {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        header("Location: " . $authUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm using the same OAuth php library for Google Analaytics. If an access token has expired, is it automatically using the refresh token? I'm still accessing the API and I know the access token I have stored has expired. I assume it's using the refresh token, if so how do I store the new access token?

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the refresh token you get the first time the user grants access to your app in a database and reuse it for future requests.

The Google Drive SDK documentation includes a sample PHP application that implements that flow  and that you can use as reference:

https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/php

Comment: The point is I don't need to make future requests: first, user signs in using google, grant access for my application and I retrieve infos like email to create an acccount if it doesn't exist. Now we have a registered user. Let's say this user logout then come back to my website and click on "login with google" he is asked to grant access once again. How can I link the refresh token to a user who's not logged anymore ?

Comment: That is explained in https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials and https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/php#authorization

Comment: I checked both links trying to understand what they do that I don't. I must be blind or missing something crucial. I see there's a function $authHandler->VerifyAuth();.Good looks like they're doing something interesting there...and nothing new: they checked for the authorization_code and if it fails check for data in $_SESSION which means this app have to ask access at every sign in.

Why it's not as easy as facebook system...user give access one time and you're good to go :o

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you aren't storing any cookies on the users computer. Sessions only store information for the duration that the user is on the website.

This is a good simple explanation on cookies. Hope it helps.

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpcookies.php

Comment: Well it could help but I think that's not the proper way. The issue at most will be delayed. Once cookies are cleared (expires or deleted by user) consent will be prompted again :<

Comment: I could be wrong however cookies are from what I understand, the only way to maintain a continuous session. Unless of course Google allows you to use it's cookies. I'm not sure though. I haven't played much with Google's API's yet.

Answer (score 0):

Set Offline access. store initial token and refresh token for each user that authenticates then no matter where the user logs into your app from they will always be connected to their Google account, even if they aren't directly logged into google itself, they will be logged into Google through your app.

Like above, this is covered in the documentation.

It would be pointless having API's if users could never do this. Also, it's nothing to do with cookies and sessions. Add the server IP to the Google developer console and you'll be fine.